# Drone CI - DRONE_HOST

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

I am trying drone on a local ubuntu, with gitlab.com

Every piece of code and example I find does not explain what the DRONE_HOST value should be as it seems to be obvious.
But what can I put in this variable ?
It seems there is some prerequisites at just launching drone locally, as drone expects to have some already drone server installation at "drone.my-company.com" (then with the uri callback with /authorize).

Does this url should exist ? Does it have to host some kind of website or a sort of "super-drone installation" in order to configure drone ? Can I put literally "whatever.nothing.com" ?

I cannot find what DRONE_HOST should refer to, as it seems to be obvious according to the documentation and discussions.

Thank you for any answer ! :-)

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

DRONE_HOST should be the IP/DOMAIN of the drone server. If you are running it in local you can use `http://localhost`

Answer (score 0):

See here http://docs.drone.io/installation/

> Drone needs to know its own address. You must therefore provide the
>   address in < scheme >://< hostname > format. Please omit trailing slashes.

Furthermore, this is the host address that will be used in webhook that is installed in the git integration of your choice as callback address. So it has to be reachable from that integration using this address.